# SQLite, Kotlin, Android. SELECT query with variate number of arguments

Tags: android, sqlite, kotlin, android-sqlite

I am building and android app with kotlin. It uses SQlite

I need to select data from a table and query condition depends on a method arguments

it is like

```
fun getData(a:String, b:String, c:String): Array<String> {
    val db = readableDatabase
    var selectALLQuery = "SELECT * FROM $TABLE "
    var conditions:ArrayList<String> = arrayListOf()
    var arguments: // WHAT should be type?

    if (a != "") {
         // add a to the query with WHERE
         conditions.add("a = ?")
         // add a value to arguments. how?
    }
    if (b != "") {
         // add b to the query with WHERE
         conditions.add("b = ?")
         // add b value to arguments. how?
    }
    if (c != "") {
         // add c to the query with WHERE
         conditions.add("c = ?")
         // add b value to arguments. how?
    }
    if (conditions.count() > 0) {
         selectALLQuery += " WHERE "+conditions.joinToString(" AND ")
    }
    val cursor = db.rawQuery(selectALLQuery, arguments)
}
```

Is this good approach? of there are better ways?
If this is corect way, what should be type of arguments variable?

**Update**

I found the solution to skip usage of SQL templates and just build a query fully myself and TEXT fields are quoted with DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString .

Comment: `MutableList<String>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`a`, `b`, `c` are all `String`s.

So you can type `arguments` as list of `String`.

```
val arguments = mutableListOf<String>()
```

Reason I used `MutableList` instead of `Array` is to dynamically add items.

Inside your `if` statements, after adding condition, you can add item to `arguments` like,

```
arguments.add(a)
```

Finally in `db.rawQuery()`, you can pass this as an array using `toTypedArray`.

```
db.rawQuery(selectALLQuery, arguments.toTypedArray())
```

## Anko

In Kotlin, you can simplify db connection and queries using **Anko**.

https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-SQLite

Check [Querying Data](https://github.com/Kotlin/anko/wiki/Anko-SQLite#querying-data) part .

Comment: The advert for Anko is totally not needed, especially considering it's inferior when compared against modern alternatives like SqlDelight, which is also fully optional.

Answer (score 1):

> var arguments: // WHAT should be type?

The rawQuery method expects an Array.

I would use

```
fun getDataV2(a: String, b: String, c: String): ArrayList<String> {

    val rv = ArrayList<String>()            //Return value
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM $TABLE "       //Core SQL ro always be used
    val values = arrayOf(a, b, c)           //Convert inputs to an array
    val columns = arrayOf("a", "b", "c")    //Likewise for the columns
    val arguments = ArrayList<String>()     //Initially 0 arguments
    val whereclause = StringBuilder()       //Initially empty whereclause
    var after_first = false                 //Flag to indicate whether the first arg has been added
    for (i in values.indices) {             //Loop through values
        if (values[i].length > 0) {         //Is there a value?
            if (after_first) {              //Is this not the first value
                whereclause.append(" AND ") //If it is not the first value add the ADD keyword
            }
            whereclause.append(columns[i]).append("=?") //if there is a value then add the expression
            arguments.add(values[i])        // and then add the value to the arguments ArrayList
            after_first = true              // change flag to indicate that a value has been processed
        }
    }
    // Add the WHERE keyword and the where clause if needed
    if (whereclause.isNotEmpty()) {
        sql = "$sql WHERE $whereclause"
    }

    //Prepare to run the rawQuery
    val db = this.writableDatabase
    //Run the rawQuery
    val csr = db.rawQuery(sql, arguments.toTypedArray())
    Log.d("GETDATAV2",sql + " Argcount =" + arguments.size) //TODO for testing, REMOVE before publising
    //Populate the ArrayList to be returned from the Cursor
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        rv.add(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLNAME))) //<<<<<<<<<< COLNAME assumed for testing
    }
    //CLose the Cursor
    csr.close()
    //Finally return the ArrayList
    return rv
}
```

## Testing

Using the following, in an activity, to test a number of premutations :-

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    val dbHelper = DBHelperKotlin(this)
    dbHelper.writableDatabase.delete(DBHelper.TABLE,null,null); //Delete any existing rows
    // Add the testing data
    dbHelper.add("Test1", "a", "b", "c")
    dbHelper.add("Test2", "b", "c", "d")
    dbHelper.add("Test3", "c", "d", "e")
    dbHelper.add("Test4", "d", "e", "f")

    //testing against older method removed (hence starting with 3) 
    val result3 = dbHelper.getDataV2("","","");
    for (i in result3.indices) {
        Log.d("TEST1V2RESULT",result3.get(i))
    }

    val result4 = dbHelper.getDataV2("","b","");
    for (i in result4.indices) {
        Log.d("TEST4V2RESULT",result4.get(i))
    }

    val result5 = dbHelper.getDataV2("a","b","c");
    for (i in result5.indices) {
        Log.d("TEST5V2RESULT",result5.get(i))
    }

    val result6 = dbHelper.getDataV2("a","","");
    for (i in result6.indices) {
        Log.d("TEST6V2RESULT",result6.get(i))
    }

    val result7 = dbHelper.getDataV2("","","c");
    for (i in result7.indices) {
        Log.d("TEST7V2RESULT",result7.get(i))
    }

    val result8 = dbHelper.getDataV2("a","","c");
    for (i in result8.indices) {
        Log.d("TEST8V2RESULT",result8.get(i))
    }
}
```

Results in

```
05-26 12:23:36.452 3593-3593/? D/GETDATAV2: SELECT * FROM mytable  Argcount =0
05-26 12:23:36.452 3593-3593/? D/TEST1V2RESULT: Test1
05-26 12:23:36.452 3593-3593/? D/TEST1V2RESULT: Test2
05-26 12:23:36.452 3593-3593/? D/TEST1V2RESULT: Test3
05-26 12:23:36.452 3593-3593/? D/TEST1V2RESULT: Test4
05-26 12:23:36.452 3593-3593/? D/GETDATAV2: SELECT * FROM mytable  WHERE b=? Argcount =1
05-26 12:23:36.453 3593-3593/? D/TEST4V2RESULT: Test1
05-26 12:23:36.453 3593-3593/? D/GETDATAV2: SELECT * FROM mytable  WHERE a=? AND b=? AND c=? Argcount =3
05-26 12:23:36.454 3593-3593/? D/TEST5V2RESULT: Test1
05-26 12:23:36.455 3593-3593/? D/GETDATAV2: SELECT * FROM mytable  WHERE a=? Argcount =1
05-26 12:23:36.455 3593-3593/? D/TEST6V2RESULT: Test1
05-26 12:23:36.455 3593-3593/? D/GETDATAV2: SELECT * FROM mytable  WHERE c=? Argcount =1
05-26 12:23:36.456 3593-3593/? D/TEST7V2RESULT: Test1
05-26 12:23:36.456 3593-3593/? D/GETDATAV2: SELECT * FROM mytable  WHERE a=? AND c=? Argcount =2
05-26 12:23:36.458 3593-3593/? D/TEST8V2RESULT: Test1
```

## However

With simple modification the above can be far more flexible and cater for any number of columns on any table (assuming the columns exist in the specified table) as per :-

```
fun getDataV3(table: String, args: Array<String>, columns: Array<String>) : ArrayList<String> {

    val rv = ArrayList<String>()            //Return value
    var sql = "SELECT * FROM $table "       //Core SQL ro always be used

    if (args.size != columns.size) {
        // handle mismatch between columns and args??????
        return rv
    }

    val arguments = ArrayList<String>()     //Initially 0 arguments
    val whereclause = StringBuilder()       //Initially empty whereclause
    var after_first = false                 //Flag to indicate whether the first arg has been added
    for (i in args.indices) {             //Loop through values
        if (args[i].length > 0) {         //Is there a value?
            if (after_first) {              //Is this not the first value
                whereclause.append(" AND ") //If it is not the first value add the ADD keyword
            }
            whereclause.append(columns[i]).append("=?") //if there is a value then add the expression
            arguments.add(args[i])        // and then add the value to the arguments ArrayList
            after_first = true              // change flag to indicate that a value has been processed
        }
    }
    // Add the WHERE keyword and the where clause if needed
    if (whereclause.isNotEmpty()) {
        sql = "$sql WHERE $whereclause"
    }

    //Prepare to run the rawQuery
    val db = this.writableDatabase
    //Run the rawQuery
    val csr = db.rawQuery(sql, arguments.toTypedArray())
    Log.d("GETDATAV3",sql + " Argcount =" + arguments.size) //TODO for testing, REMOVE before publising
    //Populate the ArrayList to be returned from the Cursor
    while (csr.moveToNext()) {
        rv.add(csr.getString(csr.getColumnIndex(COLNAME)))
    }
    //CLose the Cursor
    csr.close()
    //Finally return the ArrayList
    return rv
}
```

And can then be invoked like :-

```
    val result10 = dbHelper.getDataV3(DBHelperKotlin.TABLE,arrayOf("","",""), arrayOf(DBHelperKotlin.COLA,DBHelperKotlin.COLB,DBHelperKotlin.COLC))
    for (i in result10.indices) {
        Log.d("TEST10V2RESULT",result10.get(i))
    }
    val result11 = dbHelper.getDataV3(DBHelperKotlin.TABLE,arrayOf("","b",""), arrayOf(DBHelperKotlin.COLA,DBHelperKotlin.COLB,DBHelperKotlin.COLC))
    for (i in result11.indices) {
        Log.d("TEST11V2RESULT",result11.get(i))
    }
```

Result of the above being :-

```
05-26 12:52:24.444 3960-3960/aso.so56298529querywithmultileargs D/GETDATAV3: SELECT * FROM mytable  Argcount =0
05-26 12:52:24.444 3960-3960/aso.so56298529querywithmultileargs D/TEST10V2RESULT: Test1
05-26 12:52:24.444 3960-3960/aso.so56298529querywithmultileargs D/TEST10V2RESULT: Test2
05-26 12:52:24.444 3960-3960/aso.so56298529querywithmultileargs D/TEST10V2RESULT: Test3
05-26 12:52:24.444 3960-3960/aso.so56298529querywithmultileargs D/TEST10V2RESULT: Test4
05-26 12:52:24.444 3960-3960/aso.so56298529querywithmultileargs D/GETDATAV3: SELECT * FROM mytable  WHERE b=? Argcount =1
05-26 12:52:24.444 3960-3960/aso.so56298529querywithmultileargs D/TEST11V2RESULT: Test1
```

Comment: With strings it doesn't work. That array is not just a string. It is something like Array<out String> . IN my case if i use just Array<String> it doesn;t work

Comment: @RomanGelembjuk yep didn't test it. The above has been tested. Although really there should also be a test to ensure that the number values (arguments to the function) matches the number of columns.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe this will be helpful:

```
fun buildQuery(mainQuery: String, vararg args: Pair<String, Any>): String {
    return mainQuery + if (args.isNotEmpty()) {
         args.map {
            "${it.first} = ${it.second}"
        }.joinToString(" AND ")
    } else {
        ""
    }
}
```

Then the call is:

```
val query = buildQuery("SELECT * FROM PERSON ", "a" to "Tim", "b" to 77)
println(query)
```

The output is:

```
SELECT * FROM PERSON a = Tim AND b = 77
```

Comment: This will not work, because there is quoting of data missed. I already found DatabaseUtils.sqlEscapeString which makes quoing and in this case it would work